# Cleave.js not working in tablet devices using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cleave

I am using Cleave.js for formatting the date field in my form . My Cleave format declaration  is like this

`$scope.dobFormat = { delimiter: '/', blocks: [2, 2, 4], numericOnly: true }`

My Issue is after deleting the year if I retype the year . For the first keypress the character is not reflected on screen. This issue happens only for tablet device . For all other other screen and device it is working fine.